# How to get outside data in promise.then callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now I want to bind the data responded with function "getPresentationFilterValues" with filterItem.
How can I get the data of filter Item when calling the callback function with promise? Following is the code.

```js
$q.all(presentationPromiseList).then(
    function(response){
        for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
            config = self.bindAppPresentation(response[i], {config:config});

                var filtering = config.configuration.filtering;
              
                for(var i = 0; i< filtering.length; i++){
                    for(var j = 0; j < filtering[i].filters.length; j++){
                        var filterItem = filtering[i].filters[j];
                        if(filterItem.source == 'dynamic'&& !filterItem.options){
                            responsePromise = reveal.getPresentationFilterValues(filterItem);
                            
                            responsePromise.then(function(response){


                            }).catch(function(ex){});
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
        console.log("App presentation bind");
        return 'param1';
    },
    function(response){
        return $q.reject(new Error("failed to get app presentation: " + response.data.message));
    }
)
```

Comment: The `var i` is used twice, once in the outermost loop and again in an inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
const outsideData = 1
someFunctionWhichReturnsPromise().then(function() { return outsideData })
```

Comment: Hi, the outsideData is dynamic. It is from Array. The callback function need to get  corresponding outsideData.